# MySQL Query Return Thousands of Empty Results

Tags: php, mysql

When I run the second query to select departments it is returning my list of departments which is like 20 records, and then return thousands of blank enteries to the page freezes in a browser what did I do wrong?

```
        mysql_select_db("ita", $con);

        $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Colleges`");

        $colleges = array();

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
            {
                $colleges[] = array("Name" => $row['Name'], "Value" => $row['Value'], "ID" => $row['CollegeID']);
            }

        $collegecount = count($colleges);

        $depts = array();

        $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Departments` WHERE uid = `$uid`");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
        {
            $depts = array("Name" => $row['Name'], "Value" => $row['Value'], "ID" => $row['CollegeID']);
        }

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE wmuid = '$uid'");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

        //POPULATE FORM FIELDS FROM DB
```

Comment: Doesn't look like you're showing us the problem code.  Nothing there looks to write anything to the page.

Answer (score 2):

You have backticks around your `$uid`. I'm not sure what exactly that will do since I doubt you have a column with the same name as whatevers in `$uid`, but it's probably going to cause some weird undefined behavior. Change your `` ` `` to `'` Like:

```
SELECT * FROM `Departments` WHERE `uid` = '$uid'
```

**Edit**

Or if the column `uid` stores a numerical type remove the quotes altogether like:

```
SELECT * FROM `Departments` WHERE `uid` = $uid
```

Comment: the data type doesn't really matter when doing a SQL query. If the column is numerical, the value compared will try to convert into the same type of the column. So `uid = {$uid}` or `uid = '{$uid}'` is pretty much equivalent

Comment: +1 though as a value should not be enclosed with ``` but with a single quote `'`